# How to install VMware server 2 on Ubuntu server 11.10 ?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-server

I am trying to install VMWare server 2 on Ubuntu server 11.10, however I am getting error which seems many people are having problem with:

```
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:40: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Please don't do it!)

This is possible and [can work with certain modifications](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-vmware-server-ubuntu-fedora-opensuse/), but do you have any option to use the VMWare ESXi hypervisor instead?

The [VMWare Server product is end-of-life](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/263834) as of June 2011, and would be a *poor platform* for any new deployments.

There are a few alternatives listed at the [VMWare forums](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/263834), but you may want to look into another solution if you need to run virtualized systems from within a current Ubuntu host system.

Comment: +1 you can't stress the **don't do it** part enough.